# How to make Buttons in ListBox all the same width

Tags: wpf, button, listbox

My WPF application contains a window that has a single `ListBox` in it.  The View Model for the window contains an `ObservableCollection` of `DomainViewModel` objects.

The window defines the following `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DomainTemplate" DataType="DomainViewModel">
    <Border BorderBrush="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BrushConverter}, Path=IsSelected}"
            BorderThickness="2"
            Name="SelectedBorder">
        <Button Click="SelectDomain_Click"
                Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                FontSize="16"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Height="60"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

And here's the `ListBox`'s declaration:

```
<ListBox FontSize="16"
         FontWeight="Bold" 
         Grid.Row="2"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Domains}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DomainTemplate}"
         Name="DomainListBox" />
```

When the window renders, each button is exactly wide enough to display the text in its Content property.  But that's not what I want.  I want each button to be the width of the `ListBox`, which is going to vary with the width of the window itself.

How do I get the `Buttons` to keep their width set to the `ListBox's` width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         .../>
```